# Mysql Query - Giving only generalised result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table 'product' in which below columns are there and I want recent 2 records (Max date) for product wise

My Table :

```
ID  Product  Date
1   ProdA    2014-12-12
2   ProdB    2014-12-08
3   ProdC    2014-11-01
4   ProdD    2015-01-06
5   ProdE    2015-02-03

6   ProdA    2014-12-08
7   ProdB    2014-11-09
8   ProdC    2014-01-12
9   ProdD    2014-12-12
10  ProdE    2013-12-12

6   ProdA    2014-05-12
7   ProdB    2014-02-12
8   ProdC    2014-03-12
9   ProdD    2014-08-12
10  ProdE    2015-12-12
```

Query I Used :

```
  select count(ID) 
    from product 
order by Date desc limit 3,
```

but this would return me ID 10,5,4 of all product generalized

But I want result like it should give me 3 highest records of product wise like 3 highest record of **productA**,**ProductB** and so on
So how is it possible

Comment: Just FYI, this is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag. Occasionally, it's correctly answered too. All the ids are a bit weird in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you 2 latest record for each product:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM product AS p
        WHERE p.Product = product.Product AND p.Date >= product.Date
      ) <= 2
ORDER BY Product ASC;
```

I have ordered the products by their Product name in ascending order. You can change the last line of the query to get it in any order you want.

You can find more details about the your question here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark it as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not quite clear, but you can try the following :

```
select p.*
from `product` p
where ( select count(*)
        from `product`
        where `Product` = p.`Product` AND `Date` >= p.`Date`) < 3
order by p.`Product`
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e15d9/1)

Comment: That is fine,but i want it like I got latest 3 records of each product that is 

latest 3 records of product A , B and so on

Whereas query you have added is giving generalised that is total 3 latest records from all the product that means without taking into account the product.any clues ?

Comment: @Lerry : It is still difficult for me to understand what you want.Can you edit your question with desired result?

Comment: Let's say we have above records in table with prodcut A,B,C and forgot about D and E for now,and I want latest 2 records of all product that is out of 3 records of product A ,I want 2 records of product A with latest 2 dates and so in product B and Product C so it will be output as :

2 latest records of product A

2 latest records of product B

2 latest records of product c

Hence,output will be 

product   with date 2014-12-12

Product A with date 2014-12-08

Product B with date 2014-12-08

Product B with date 2014-11-09

Product C with date  2014-11-01

Product C with date  2014-03-12

Comment: Hence,my main concern is it should give latest records date wise but also with product wise and not only 2 records of any product so if we have total 10 products in table,then in output it should be 20 records containing each product twice with latest 2 date

Comment: did my explanation make sense ?

Comment: @Lerry : Once again: you want 2 latest records for each product?

Comment: Yes,latest 2 records of each product